# SQL Query to processes customer table value for last six months transaction and add new columns flag and count based on processed value

Tags: sql

`I have a customer table having columns

```
custname, value=> values(
x,  0011001,
y,  1100101,
z,  1111010,
a,  0111111)
```

Question: Process customer table and add new columns flag and number of default transactions. 1 means successful transaction , 0 means default transaction from last 6 months in the cloumn value. Result should be like below.

```
custname,   value,  flag,   number=> values(
x,  0011001,    Y,  3,
Y,  1100101,    Y,  3,
Z,  1111010,    Y,  2,
A,  0111111,    N,  0)
```

I have trying like below but not able to complete please suggest and help.

```
Alter table customer add flag VARCHAR 2, number INTEGER ;
UPDATE Table customer set flag = N  WHRE select value from customer)
SET NUMBER  = SELECT COUNT(VALUE) FROM CUSTOMER WEHRE`
```